# Can a character with the Healer feat use the second benefit of the feat to heal themselves?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, healing

The second benefit of the [Healer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/healer) feat (PHB, p. 167) gives me the following action:

> - As an action, you can spend one use of a healer’s kit to tend to a
>     creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points to it, plus additional hit
>     points equal to the creature’s maximum number of Hit Dice. The
>     creature can’t regain hit points from this feat again until it
>     finishes a short or long rest.

Can I use this ability to heal myself?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes, you are a creature

There isn't much more to say here, if you weren't an eligble target, the feature would have said so, for example by including wording like "tend to *another* creature" or "a creature other than you" like the Bard's Bardic Inspiration feature.